# Return None using re group () in python

Tags: python, regex

The text file (itemsList) that i work on it have this format:

```
id "item 1"
str "item 1 description"

id "item 2"
str "item 2 description"
```

and tried to read this file in Python like this:

```
import re
itemList= open('itemsList.txt', encoding="utf8")
items=''
pattern = re.compile('(id\s)(\"(.*)\")|(str\s)(\"(.*)\")',re.IGNORECASE)
for item in itemList:
    Result = re.search(pattern,item)
    if Result:
        items+= Result.group(3)
    else:
        items+= "\n"
```

I got this error:

```
TypeError: must be str, not NoneType
```

Editing `Result.group(3)` to `str(Result.group(3))`
giving this None with the group:

```
item 1None
item 2None
```

the expected result should be like:

```
item 1, item 1 description
item 2, item 2 description
```

Comment: `items=''` is an empty string. You must have meant `for item in itemList:`. Also, there is no use in `str()`s, just use `Result.group(n)`.

Comment: i mede a mistake when i wrote the question ... that is correct i mean 
for item in itemList:
but removing the str gave me this error:
TypeError: must be str, not NoneType

Comment: Because there is no match.

Comment: Use the [edit] button to fix your question. Also show what your expected output for the example you have given should be. Are you trying to convert the file into a CSV formatted file?

Comment: I'd like to express my appreciation that you only have to search "python Match group None", and your answer is literally the first thing that opens and gives the extremely relevant explanation. Thank you, Internet. Keep up the good work, MaxDev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regular expressions uses `|`. As such will either get a match on the first 3 groups you have, or on the second 3 groups. The other group values with be returned as `None`. So if for example `id` is matched, `Result.group(3)` would contain the value otherwise `Result.group(6)` would contain your value:

```
import re

itemList= open('itemsList.txt', encoding="utf8")
items = ''

pattern = re.compile('(id\s)(\"(.*)\")|(str\s)(\"(.*)\")',re.IGNORECASE)

for item in itemList:
    Result = re.search(pattern,item)

    if Result:
        if Result.group(3):
            items += Result.group(3) + ','
        else:
            items += Result.group(6)
    else:
        items += "\n"        

print(items)
```

This would print the following:

```
item 1,item 1 description
item 2,item 2 description
```

An alternative approach would be to avoid using regular expressions and instead treat it as a special case of a CSV file. In this case a space character would be the delimiter, and the quotes would automatically be treated as a separate value. You can then use the same library to save your rows back to a new file:

```
import csv

with open('input.txt', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter=' ')
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    block = []

    for row in csv_input:
        if len(row):
            block.append(row)
        elif block:
            csv_output.writerow([block[0][1], block[1][1]])
            block = []

    if block:            
        csv_output.writerow([block[0][1], block[1][1]])
```

In your code, you keep appending strings to create your line. In Python this is not the preferred solution. It is better to append all your values into a list, and to then process the list.

`csv_output.writerow()` takes a list of row values, and automatically adds the necessary `,` and newline characters when writing to the file.

I suggest you add `print(row)` and `print(block)` to understand how it is working.